# C# what is the exclamation point positioned after the parameter name

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

This is my very first question here. I bumped into a method like this in C#:

```
void Do(string action!) { ... }
```

And don't get what the `!` after `action` is and it does. Can you help me understand it?

Comment: Possibly not a duplicate - this is the use of the operator in argument lists which appears to be a new language feature.

Comment: @mtone Ah, my bad. I'll re-open it then.

Comment: This code won't compile yet, since [this feature](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145) isn't implemented yet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is named the bang operator, `!`, which can be positioned after any identifier in a parameter list and this will cause the `C#` compiler to emit standard null checking code for that parameter. For example:

```
void Do(string action!) { ... }
```

Will be translated into:

```
void Do(string action!) {
    if (action is null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    }
    ...
}
```

btw, at the moment, this feature is not available yet. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145).

Comment: [This feature](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145) isn't implemented yet

Comment: I cannot use this? when can I?

Comment: not yet and it's just a matter of writing lesser code and you can survive without it :)

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

you use the null-forgiving operator to declare that expression x of a reference type isn't null

Comment: This is illegal in the example the OP gave (on a parameter).

Comment: @YairHalberstadt in this time of writing, the linked article explain both scenarios - one which is equivalent to what OP asked for and the other is when you know an expression cannot be null, e.g. (as taken from the link): 

`null!` and `p!.Name`